# GeoJSON to routing graph

Tags: geojson, routing, geometric-network, graph

What are the best automated ways of placing the nodes and edges of a routing graph using the GeoJSON data of a multi-level building? What other data is needed (area layout, accessor directions etc)?

Comment: welcome to GIS@SE, you need to specify the systems, databases  and software packages, versions, you are using to get a meaningful answer. Please edit you question to include this information.

Comment: Hi Hink, did you manage to do anything meaningful/useful?